# Review Queues mismatch

Tags: bug, reviews

This has been happening for me quite often recently, and it's strange. I look at my Review Queue, and there's a shining red dot next to the Low Quality Posts. As pictured:

[image]

I click on it, and there's nothing - "this queue has been cleared". It's not a situation of caching and refreshing: the red dot stays there for hours, and multiple refreshes. It's even there when I'm *on the relevant reviews page, and the page is empty*. And interestingly, it's only the red dot that's acting out. The regular grey one works as intended - it's there when there's stuff to review, it's not there when there's nothing.

That's not how it's supposed to work, is it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a known issue since the change to dots indicator: [Please don't show the red dot indicator for review items I can't do](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/310798). It means that *there still are* pending reviews in the queue, but you are *not* eligible to review them. Some possible causes:

> - There are items in a queue which the user does not have the reputation to review. (I only know of this happening in the suggested edits queue, where tag wiki edits land in the same queue as post edits.) This once [caused me some consternation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307408/im-not-that-bad-why-cant-i-review).
> - There is a single pending suggested edit, which is currently being reviewed by someone else and has been "checked out" to that reviewer.
> - **The reviewer has already voted on a post in the queue (e.g. flagging a current Low Quality post as NAA or VLQ externally, or externally voting to close or reopen a post currently in one of those queues)**
> - **The reviewer has skipped reviews**
> - [The user has had a review ban](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/310783/red-dot-indicator-appears-even-when-im-banned-from-reviewing)
> - **The user has reviewed all items in a queue, but they have not left it yet**
>
> <sup>(Emphasis mine)</sup>